# Proteger tabela Mysql contra drop

Tags: mysql

Tenho um módulo Wordpress (Cerber) que por alguma razão obscura, está deletando uma tabela (cerber_files). O desenvolvedor não se manifesta.

Gostaria de saber se há algum comando que evite que uma tabela mysql seja eliminidada (drop)?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o comando REVOKE para fazer isso. Um exemplo:

```
REVOKE DROP ON minha_tabela FROM nome_do_usuario;
```

O nome_do_usuario seria o usuário utilizado pelo Wordpress para conectar no banco.

Aqui tem mais informações:

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/grant_revoke.php

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-revoke.aspx

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_drop

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu tentei fazer 
`REVOKE DROP ON cerber_files FROM rogeriod_sestra;` via PhpMyAdmin mas aparentemente o comando `REVOKE` não está sendo reconhecido:
`Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "REVOKE" at position 0)
SQL query:

REVOKE DROP ON cerber_files FROM rogeriod_sestra

MySQL said: Documentation

#1142 - GRANT command denied to user 'rogeriod'@'localhost' for table 'cerber_files'`